# Shacharit on י"א תשרי

Tags: sources-mekorot, minhag, yom-kippur, ashkenazi

I have heard that there is a minhag in ashkenazi communities to daven shacharit on the morning after yom hakippurim a bit earlier than the time that one would normally daven shacharit. Anyone have the source for that minhag?

Comment: Correct, in our shul we start 2 minutes before the regular time. Makes me smile every year.

Comment: That would cause total chaos in my Shul - 6 Minyanim, 4 of them finally back to regular schedule (different times for Selichos) - and the 2 minutes would probably just get used up discussing the change...and then start at regular time.

Answer (score 7):

This custom is noted in [Matteh Ephraim 624:14](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mateh_Efrayim.624.14?lang=he).

Answer (score 4):

The Be'er Heitiv 624:6 also notes to daven early, the morning after Yom Kippur.